# How can I prove that the following estimator is biased?

Tags: econometrics, statistics

I'm trying to prove that $e^{x\hat{\beta}}-1$ is  a biased estimator for $e^{x \beta}-1$. I know that this involves taking the expected value of the estimator and showing that it is not equal to $e^{x \beta}-1$. Unfortunately, I'm stuck on the math. Any hints?

Comment: Use Jensen's inequality

Comment: For convex function $g$, $\mathbb{E}(g(X)) \geq g(\mathbb{E}(X))$. If $g$ is strictly convex then inequality is strict: $\mathbb{E}(g(X)) > g(\mathbb{E}(X))$.